# Account class not working properly

Tags: java, class

```
public class AccountDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // ID, Balance, Annual Interest Rate
        Account number1 = new Account();
        Account number2 = new Account(1122, 20000.00, 0.045);

        // Default account
        System.out.println("The Account ID is:  " + number1.getId());
        System.out.println("The Account Balance is: " + number1.getBalance());
        // System.out.println("The Account Balance is: "+
        // number1.getMontlyInterest());
        System.out.println("");

        // Ask to withdraw 2500
        System.out.println("The Account ID is:  " + number2.getId());
        number2.withdraw(2500.00);
        number2.deposit(3000.00);
        System.out.println("Account Balance is " + number2.getBalance());
        // System.out.println("The montly interest is : "+
        // number2.getMontlyInterest());
        System.out.println("");

    }
}

public class Account {

    private int id = 0;
    private double balance = 0;
    private double annualInterestRate = 0;

    public Account(int id, double balance, double annualInterestRate) {
        this.setId(id);
        this.setBalance(this.balance);
        this.setBalance(annualInterestRate);
    }

    public Account() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public double getAnnualInterestRate() {
        return annualInterestRate;
    }

    public void setAnnualInterestRate(double annualInterestRate) {
        this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
    }

    public double getMontlyInterest(double montlyInterest) {
        // Given Formula
        // double MontlyInterest= this.balance * get.MontlyInterestRate();
        return montlyInterest;
    }

    public double getMontlyInterestRate(double montlyInterestRate) {
        // Given Formula
        montlyInterestRate = this.annualInterestRate / 12;
        return montlyInterestRate;

    }

    double withdraw(double amount) {
        return balance -= amount;
    }

    double deposit(double amount) {
        return balance += amount;
    }
}
```

I am getting error

The Account ID is:  0
The Account Balance is: 0.0

The Account ID is:  1122
Account Balance is 20500.0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method getMontlyInterestRate(double) in the type Account is not applicable for the arguments ()

```
at Account.getMontlyInterest(Account.java:41)
at AccountDriver.main(AccountDriver.java:21)
```

Comment: Why are you call `this.setBalance(annualInterestRate);` twice in the `Account` constructor, passing the `annualInterestRate`?

Comment: Oh it should be this.setBalance(this.annualInterestRate); Right?

Comment: No!  It should be `this.setAnnualInterestRate(annualInterestRate);` and the `setBalance` call before it should be `this.setBalance(balance);` - note that the parameters ARE NOT prefixed with `this`!

Comment: What about the montly interest method?

Answer (score 2):

You did 2 small mistakes in your code.

In your constructor these 2 lines

```
this.setBalance(this.balance); // this.balance is the instance variable and not the parameter passed
                ^^^^ - this is not required, just use the balance parameter passed.
this.setBalance(annualInterestRate); // you are re-writing the balance with interest rate
     ^^^^^^^^^^ - You need to set annual interest rate and not the balance here.
```

should be

```
this.setBalance(balance); // sets the balance passed to the instance variable balance
this.setAnnualInterestRate(annualInterestRate); // sets the annual interest rate
```

---

Now since the `annualInterestRate` is set, you can get the monthly interest rate by modifying `getMontlyInterestRate` method like this.

```
public double getMontlyInterestRate() {
    // Given Formula
return this.annualInterestRate / 12;
}
```

And you can print your monthly interest rate by uncommenting your `System.out.println` code.

```
System.out.println("The montly interest is : "+ number2.getMontlyInterestRate());
```

---

And the monthly interest method would look like this:

```
public double getMontlyInterest() { // no parameter required
    // Given Formula
    double MontlyInterest = this.balance * getMontlyInterestRate(); // balance multiplied by monthly interest rate
    return MontlyInterest; // return the value
}

System.out.println("The montly interest is : "+ number2.getMontlyInterest());
```

Comment: @RJ You might need to point `this.balance`, as it's a little less the obvious to see...

Comment: I got it, thank you. What about the montlyInterest rate, I put // so the program can compile it

Comment: The montly interest rate is fine the problem is the montly interest method

Comment: @user3304653 - Talking like this would take you nowhere. Check out the edits I make and try them. Don't shout here because everybody is here to help you. (ALL CAPS MEANS LITERALLY YELLING AT THE OTHER PERSON AND I CAN DO THAT AS WELL, BUT I DON"T WANT TO).

Comment: Oh am sorry I didn't know that

Comment: @user3304653 - With the current revision of my answer, your program should work just fine. Am not sure what error you're getting now. Make all the changes I've done in my answer, including the change of monthyinterestrate method. Both methods need to be changed.

Comment: What it is in the edits is exactly what I have, but it says that "Get cannot be resolved"

Comment: Where do you get that error? In which line exactly?

Comment: it is next to the line double MontlyInterest= (this.balance * get.MontlyInterestRate());

Comment: get is underline in red

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method getMontlyInterest(double) in the type Account is not applicable for the arguments ()

 at AccountDriver.main(AccountDriver.java:21)

Comment: `double MontlyInterest = this.balance * getMontlyInterestRate();` - Did you even do the changes I did? I clearly changed your code. Without making the changes, you'll obviously get these errors. Replace your methods in your code with the once I've provided.

Comment: Yes that is what I have, I double check it and I even copy and pasted your code

Comment: The Account ID is:  0
The Account Balance is: 0.0

The Account ID is:  1122
Account Balance is 20500.0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method getMontlyInterestRate(double) in the type Account is not applicable for the arguments ()

 at Account.getMontlyInterest(Account.java:41)
 at AccountDriver.main(AccountDriver.java:21)

Comment: In the solution I gave, `public double getMontlyInterest() {` doesn't have a parameter. This is the change I asked you to make, but you did not do that at all. Copy paste the whole method along with the declaration. Both the `getMontlyInterestRate` and `getMontlyInterest` method do not take any input parameters. Change the code to reflect that.