# Account class showing error

Tags: java, class

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    //ID, Balance, Annual Interest Rate 
        Account number1 = new Account();
        Account number2 = new Account(1122,20000.00,0.045);     
    
    
       //Default account
        System.out.println("The Account ID is:  " + number1.getId());
        System.out.println("The Account Balance is: "+ number1.getBalance());
        //System.out.println("The Account Balance is: "+ number1.getMontlyInterest());
        System.out.println("");
        
        //Ask to withdraw 2500
        System.out.println("The Account ID is:  " + number2.getId());
        number2.withdraw(2500.00);
        number2.deposit(3000.00);
        System.out.println("Account Balance is "+ number2.getBalance());
        System.out.println("The montly interest is : "+ number2.getMontlyInterest());
        System.out.println("");
        
    }
}


public class Account {

    private int id=0;
    private double balance=0;
    private double annualInterestRate=0;
    
        
    public Account(int id, double balance, double annualInterestRate) {
        this.setId(id);
        this.setBalance(balance);
        this.setAnnualInterestRate(annualInterestRate);
    
    }
    
    public Account() {
        
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }
    public double getAnnualInterestRate() {
        return annualInterestRate;
    }
    public void setAnnualInterestRate(double annualInterestRate) {
        this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
    }

    public double getMontlyInterest() {
    //Given Formula 
        double MontlyInterest = this.balance * getMontlyInterestRate();
        return MontlyInterest;
    }
    
        
    public double getMontlyInterestRate(double montlyInterestRate){
    //Given Formula
        montlyInterestRate= this.annualInterestRate/12;
        return montlyInterestRate;
    
    }
        
    
    double withdraw(double amount){
    
    return balance -=amount;
    }
    
    
    double deposit(double amount){
    
    return balance += amount;   
    }
}
```

This is the error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: The method `getMontlyInterest(double)` in the type `Account` is not applicable for the `arguments ()`
>
> at `AccountDriver.main(AccountDriver.java:21)`

I am try different things but it still doesn't work

Comment: Where is your `AccountDriver` class

Comment: Use an IDE. It catches these type of errors while you are writing and gives you reason for error as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Account class not working propertly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746201/account-class-not-working-propertly)

Comment: This is a different error problem

Comment: @user3304653 - It is the same problem. You haven't tried the solution I gave at all. I told you to remove the parameters in the method declaration but you've not made that change at all and thus are still stuck with the same problem.

Comment: Why do I need to add 40 on montly interest method to make the program work????

Comment: @user3304653 - Even this method `getMontlyInterestRate(){` shouldn't have a parameter. I mentioned this as well in my solution there.

Comment: Thank you I was looking at the other one, I am just too frustrated with this I was blind. Thank you

Comment: @user3304653 you edited your post to remove the actual problem.  Now the post makes no sense (even if it already did little).  Don't do that.

Answer (score 4):

Your method `getMontlyInterestRate` requires an argument (the monthly interest) rate, you did not give any in your main.

> System.out.println("The montly interest is : "+
>   number2.getMontlyInterest());

In fact you do not need your argument `double montlyInterestRate` because you assign it inside the method ... Just remove it:

```
public double getMontlyInterestRate(/*montlyInterestRate*/)
{
    double montlyInterestRate= this.annualInterestRate/12;
    return montlyInterestRate;
}
```

and it is the same in your method `getMontlyInterest`:

```
public double getMontlyInterest(/*double montlyInterest*/) {
    //Given Formula 
        double montlyInterest = this.balance * getMontlyInterestRate();
        return montlyInterest;
    }
```

Comment: like that double x= Account.getMontlyInterestRate(montlyInterestRate);

Comment: like this System.out.println("The montly interest is : "+ number2.getMontlyInterest(40.0));

Comment: WHy do I need to put 40.0?

Comment: your function getMontlyInterestRate(double d) is taking a double value as parameter and 40.0 is double